# Cannot CAST '33.33' to INT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have encountered a problem where the `WHERE` clause is causing a problem.  The `varcharColumn` is of datatype `VARCHAR` and contains numbers as well as text.  The query looks to be averaging this column, but it has now hit a problem when a number has a decimal, e.g. 33.33.

```
SELECT AVG(CONVERT(INT,[varcharColumn])) 
  FROM View 
 WHERE [varcharColumn] > 0 
   AND [varcharColumn] <> 'NA' 
   AND CreatedDate > @StartDate AND CreatedDate <@EndDate
```

Now, I have tried to `CAST` and `CONVERT` the `varcharColumn` in the `WHERE` clause, but this returns no results.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to round 33.33 or ignore it?

Comment: BTW: There is no guarantee that the `WHERE [varcharColumn] <> 'NA'` will run before the Cast to int.

Comment: @gbn: I would need to round it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT AVG(cast(cast([varcharColumn] as decimal) as int))
      FROM View 
     WHERE isnumeric([varcharColumn]) = 1 
     AND cast(cast([varcharColumn] as decimal) as int) > 0
     AND CreatedDate > @StartDate AND CreatedDate < @EndDate
```

[image]

Comment: `CAST([varcharColumn] AS INT) > 0` will fail because it cannot convert '33.33' to INT.

Comment: this will select cast(CAST('33.33' as decimal)as int)

Comment: you are assuming a certain order of execution (the ISNUMERIC will be evaluated before the CAST) which is [not guaranteed](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/).

Comment: its a very nice article @RemusRusanu, but i think its fixed in sql 2008, i attached the execution plan of both cases where isnumeric before cast and isnumeric after cast, i dont see no difference in the execution plan

Comment: This cannot be 'fixed', as is not a bug. Is an incorrect assumption on your side. The execution plan can change at any moment. Given that the cast and the check occur on the *same* column, is very unlikely to ever happen. But do not *assume* it can never happen.

Comment: Just for others viewing this answer, I'm only using the `CAST` part from the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a useful scalar function to simulate the TRY_CAST function of SQL SERVER 2012 in SQL Server 2008.

```
dbo.TRY_CAST(Expression, Data_Type, ReturnValueIfErrorCast)
```

You can see it in the next link below and we help each other to improve it. *TRY_CAST Function for SQL Server 2008* https://gist.github.com/jotapardo/800881eba8c5072eb8d99ce6eb74c8bb

**With TRY_CAST of SQL Server 2012**

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('33.33' as int) AS Result
```

->

```
Result
-----------
NULL

(1 row(s) affected)
```

**With dbo.TRY_CAST function for sql server 2008**

```
SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST('33.33', 'INT',DEFAULT) AS Result
```

->

```
Result
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
33

(1 row(s) affected)
```

> The two main differences are that you must pass 3 parameters and you
>   must additionally perform an explicit CONVERT or CAST to the field.
>   However, it is still very useful because it allows you to return a
>   default value if CAST is not performed correctly.

**Example:**

```
SELECT   CASE WHEN dbo.TRY_CAST('6666666166666212', 'INT', DEFAULT) IS NULL   
                        THEN 'Cast failed'  
                        ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  
                    END AS Result;
```

> Additionally, you can pass a default value if the cast is not successful.
>
> ```
> SELECT dbo.TRY_CAST('text', 'INT', -1) AS Result
> ```
>
> ->
>
> ```
> Result
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> -1
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
> ```

For now only supports the data types **INT, DATE, NUMERIC** and **BIT**